# RSA decryption with public key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, rsa, public-key

I have a php code that will encrypt data with private key and I want to decrypt that data on client side with public key. Many JavaScript libraries only supports decrypt with private key. Encryption with public key and decryption with private key is working but vice versa not working.

Is there a way to decrypt with public key in JavaScript?

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsencrypt/3.0.0/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
</head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="" id= "canvas"></div>
    <script>
        // Create a new RSA key pair
        const privatekey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nYgFx+1dCJOKwMR7F+ue3Q1SRZA==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';

        const publickey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxzJB3GQVjAhLmfZzr/TS\nEhNAHj1XGv46ZpkGwbFf11XUC429UzAbcWTXlSrvPZZOzuo4SC1T+x3MazsvW3J9\n9ZjHhtF7mP4r1q1BMJs+J7iwaohujdayNlS79CgseK1e8hBxi/J79BC9svvCEg1D\n7sLVjPp7IdgMRLlLqrEwxDi47ZiRyBs/kUYm5nUuTsxzDbVEtzz/sLJ7h/TFumwl\n9CXta5virHoHcvwW1QKdsKTk3AGsdkYeIVpttU2FytzkmvCnXYjQtmV7/aWtMH/z\n43jDs/UHcv2Ugfyq2lo0ATvuSTb5x488AH5jykudsc6iCGu2N9RsDhKeyRySY4Lu\ngwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n';


        console.log('Private Key:\n', privatekey);
        console.log('Public Key:\n', publickey);

        const en = new JSEncrypt();
        const dn = new JSEncrypt();

        en.setPrivateKey(privatekey);
        dn.setPublicKey(publickey);
        // Data to be encrypted
        const originalData = 'Stackoverflow';
        // Encrypt the data
         const encryptedData = en.encrypt(originalData);

        console.log('Encrypted Data:', encryptedData);
        // Decrypt the data
        console.log('Encrypted Data:', encryptedData);
        const decryptedData = dn.decrypt(encryptedData);

        console.log('Decrypted Data:', decryptedData);

        // Check if the decryption is successful
        const decryptionSuccessful = decryptedData === originalData;
        console.log('Decryption Successful:', decryptionSuccessful);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In an asymmetrical encryption scheme, messages encrypted with a private key can only be decrypted by a public key, while messages encrypted with a public key can only be decrypted with the private key. What have you tried so far; could you show us the code you used for decrypting on  JS? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @Haroldo_OK, added JavaScript code. I know how symmetrical encryption works, I am trying to decrypt(with public key) the message encrypted with a private key

Comment: JSEncrypt does not support *encryption with the private key*. You may be confusing this with signing. Have a look at the JSEncrypt documentation.

Comment: @Topaco yes JSEncrypt does not support encryption with the private key, is there any JavaScript library that supports encryption with private key and decryption with public key

Comment: *Encryption with the private key* is not consistently defined and is thus implemented differently by libraries. Some do not support it at all, some perform (low level) signing (in which the padding of the signing is used), others extract the public key and perform a normal encryption... You must therefore describe your use case, or specify the logic in detail (especially with regard to encoding and padding).

Comment: My use case is, there are two clients with separate RSA key pairs and each client will share their public key with other clients. Client 1 encrypt some data with private key and share it with client 2, now client 2 has to decrypt encrypted data with client 1's public key

Comment: Why on earth are you encrypting with the private key? You have to encrypt with the recipient's public key. This is the only way to ensure that only the recipient can decrypt (since only the recipient has the corresponding private key), s. [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation). If the sender encrypts with their private key, *anyone* can decrypt, because by definition anyone can have the sender's public key.

Comment: yes that's what I want, anyone has sender's public key should able to decrypt. I want to know is that possible or not.  It is working in other platforms like php and flutter only facing issue in JavaScript

Comment: As already mentioned: *Encryption with the private key* is not standardized and is not implemented consistently by libraries. So you have to look for a library that supports something like this (e.g. in the context of low level signing), and then use it for your own purposes. But again the warning (if not in the context of signing): 1. it is an abuse of RSA, 2. it is about as secure as not encrypting at all.